# local connection only

Tags: internet, networking, connection

What are some tip or things that you would try if you were somewhere; hospital, hotel, etc., and were trying to connect to the internet via there wireless router but your connection says local only?

Answer (score 3):

It can really mean anything, the main reasons are :

- It can be a security precaution - wrong key so router "allows" you to connect, but nothing works
- There simply is no internet and it is an ad-hoc network that is used just for sharing files
  or simple networking
- There is no DHCP server on the network - you have to set manually
- You have manually typed in an incorrect IP / Network settings
- You have internet security software (Firewall or similar) that is preventing you to connect
- You are connected, using a non standard IP structure (such as link-local) and you need to open up IE or Firefox without a No script type add-on so you can redirect to a log on / payment page.

Again, there are more, but I think that these are the main ones.